# Double array to wav

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

I want to export a double[] array to a wav file. I'm having some trouble manipulating the headers (RIFF, fmt, etc) . Any ideas how I should approach this? Maybe use BitConverter to turn the double[] array into a byte[] array and then use NAudio's waveFileWriter? Any sample code much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use WaveFileWriter's `WriteSample` method to write each sample one by one, or `WriteSamples` to do it in one hit. Since you have an array of doubles, you can use a bit of LINQ to convert to a float array first.

```
float[] floatArray = doubleArray.Select(s => (float)s).ToArray();
writer.WriteSamples(floatArray, 0, floatArray.Length);
```

This will write each sample to the `WaveFileWriter`, converting to the correct bit depth (e.g. 16 bit or 32 bit IEEE float), which depends on the WaveFormat you selected when you opened the `WaveFileWriter`

Comment: Thank you Mark! NAudio looks really awesome by the way! Kudos! I'll get into it soon ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to write all of the necessary bits of the WAV file according to standards. You will have issues with mono vs. stereo and sampling rate issues too. Strongly recommended you look form some source code that already exists that deals with this issues (I did not find a any C# version in a quick search, though there were several C/C++ version). Trying to write the code just based on a header spec will be hit or miss

Comment: Didn't find any existing code myself either. The only "shortcut" I'm aware of is NAudio, yet I'm not sure of the way to implement this with it. Found this http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.gr/2011/04/how-to-use-wavefilewriter.html , yet it assumes that the input array is consisted of bytes

Comment: Raw audio is bytes (actually word 16 bit words usually). What does your floating point data look like?

Comment: I look at the page your referenced, it has an example of converting floating to a byte stream.

Comment: Have you looked at the NAUDIO tutorials hosted on youtube? Looks like combining tutorials 6 & 7 should give you what you want

Comment: You mean what do the values look like? My data is a double array. The first 3 values for example are these: -0.0013002557988597064, 0.0014071145346131924,0.011843159708621626 . So, Gary you say i cast the array as a float and use waveFileWriter?

Comment: Are all of the value in the range -1.0 to +1.0?

Comment: OK, last thing is you may need to scale by multiplyinh to 32767 for 16 bit encoding -- notice the amplitude parameter in the example